# Swift Como salir de la aplicacion

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Basicamente eso , como puedo cerrar la aplicacion ya que no encuentro casi informacion al respecto y me gustaria añadir esa funcion a un boton del navigation controller para que el usuario salga de la aplicacion cuando lo desee , he visto que hablan del exit() pero no lo recomiendan por que esto lo entiende como un crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `iOS` nunca se debe cerrar la aplicación mediante `exit()` o similar. Simplemente, el botón `Home` del `iPhone` está para eso. Es una **muy** mala práctica cerrar la aplicación mediante programación.

Comment: mmm ya veo , muchas gracias es que tenia esa duda

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta es acerca de en Swift como lograr que la aplicación salga programaticamente, NO existe una API oficialmente para realizarlo, pero una forma para lograrlo es similar a las aplicaciones iOS, se puede realizar mediante la ejecuciòn del mètodo:

```
exit(0);
```

Es importante leer la documentación sobre el uso de este método:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html

> **Atencion**: No llamar la funcion exit(). Aplicaciones que usan este
>   metodo puede registrarse al usuario que tuvieron error. En lugar de
>   realizar una terminación elegante y la animación a la pantalla de
>   inicio.